# Hidden Treasure Logic Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

[image]
Ok, fellow puzzlers, here is my latest puzzle. They are getting progressively harder.

### Back Story

While snooping around your grandpa’s attic, you came across a bunch of scribbled notes. They were in no particular order, but you could clearly see they were coordinates pointing to Hidden Treasure!

Using the clues I provided, figure out the day each treasure was found, as well as the latitude and longitude where each was found, and determine what was discovered inside each treasure box (you're good if you can do this!).

### Puzzle Data

**Longitude:**

88.0431 W , 88.1928 W , 88.3821 W , 88.4584 W

**Latitudes**

40.2516 N , 40.3109 N , 40.5912 N , 41.0237 N

**Days**

May 3 , May 6 , May 9, May 12

### The Clues

> Clue #1

The cache at **41.0237 N** was found 6 days after the cache at **40.2516 N**.

> Clue #2

The box found on May 3 was either the case at **88.1928 W** or the box at 40.3109 N

> Clue #3

The cache at **41.0237** N was found 3 days before the box at **88.3821 W**.

> Clue #4

The cache at **88.4584 W** was found sometime after the cache at **40.3109 N**.

**Blank Answer Grid**

[image]

**Hint: Puzzle Grid**
If you want to use a traditional logic puzzle grid, I made you one below.

> [image]

### Good Luck Puzzlers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the provided grid:

> [image: solution grid]
>  (with the colours done in order, based on the information of the clues indicated)

The solution is:

> `May 3  -  40.2516 N  -  88.1928 W`
>  `May 6  -  40.3109 N  -  88.0431 W`
>  `May 9  -  41.0237 N  -  88.4584 W`
>  `May 12 -  40.5912 N  -  88.3821 W`

Comment: AWESOME work, so quickly. I think your method of solving appears to be very efficient! Perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier I’ll change longitudes’ and latitudes’ values with numbers from 1 to 8.

Longitude:
88.0431 W (1) , 88.1928 W (2) , 88.3821 W (3), 88.4584 W (4);

Latitudes
40.2516 N (5), 40.3109 N (6), 40.5912 N (7), 41.0237 N (8).

Days
May 3 , May 6 , May 9, May 12

**My thoughts:**

**1. The cache at 41.0237 N (8) was found 6 days after the cache at
       40.2516 N (5).**

> So (5) could either be in the 3 or the 6 of May, while (8) in the 9 or 12.

**2. The box found on May 3 was either the case at 88.1928 W (2)or the box at 40.3109 N (6).**

> So on the 3 or may we could either have (2) or (6).

**3. The cache at 41.0237 N (8) was found 3 days before the box at 88.3821 W (3).**

Since (8) is either on May 9 or 12, it has to be after one of these dates. But we don’t have may 15 so we can deduce that:

- (8)

  > is of course on May 9;
- (5)

  > is ahead of 6 days, so it’s on May 3;
- (2)

  > is on May 3 as well since either (6) or (2) were on May 3 and we can’t have (6) since we already have (5);
- (3)

  > is on May 12, three days after (8).

So, we still have two free latitude spaces we have to fill with (6) and (7), and we have two longitude spaces to fill with (1) and (4).

** 4. The cache at 88.4584 W (4) was found sometime after the cache at 40.3109 N (6).**

Our free latitude spaces are May 6 and May 7. While our latitude spaces are May 6 and May 9.
This said we of course have:

- (4)

  > on May 9 since it comes after (6);
- (6)

  > on May 6 since it comes before (4);

Then we only have one space left for longitude and one for latitude so we easily fill them:

- (7)

  > on May 12;
- (1)

  > on May 6.

**SO MY RESULTS ARE:**

> May 3: (2) and (5);

---

> May 6: (1) and (6);

---

> May 9: (4) and (8);

---

> May 12: (3) and (7).